# How do I apply version control in a "low-code" environment (i.e. SAC Analytic Application Designer)?

Tags: version-control, sap-analytics-cloud, lowcode

How do I apply version control in a "low-code" environment (i.e. SAC Analytic Application Designer)?

I am using [SAC Analytic Application Designer](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ANALYTICS_CLOUD/00f68c2e08b941f081002fd3691d86a7/25a3b8d145864d7faf7447b916e492e7.html) to create dashboards for our users.
It's a drag & drop environment with optional use of basic JS scripts on existing components and CSS for styling.

I am a little anxious about not having anything like a remote backup or a version control tool. Editing scripts straight in the Designer feels insecure.

It might also be my personal bias of being used to using git for basically anything what contains any code.

I try using gitlab together with SAC, but without any form of integration it is quite tedious and feels wrong. It's manual copying and pasting source code between one IDE to another.

Is there a preferred way of ensuring backup and version control in such environments?